# How to do deep sets and gets in Go's map[string]interface{}?

Tags: json, go

If I have some arbitrary JSON how can I do deep sets and gets on the nested properties using a slice of map keys and/or slice indexes?

For example, in the following excerpt from the [JSON API example](http://jsonapi.org/):

```
{
    "data": [{
        "type": "posts",
        "id": "1",
        "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
        "links": {
            "self": "http://example.com/posts/1",
            "author": {
                "self": "http://example.com/posts/1/links/author",
                "related": "http://example.com/posts/1/author",
                "linkage": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I'd like to get the string `"9"` located at `data.0.links.author.linkage.id` using something like:

```
[]interface{}{"data",0,"links","author","linkage","id"}
```

I know the ideal way to do this is to create nested structs that map to the JSON object which I do for production code, but sometimes I need to do some quick testing which would be nice to do in Go as well.

Comment: This can be done with 2 simple helper functions which I proposed [here in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28878037/1705598).

Comment: Thanks icza! That's what I'm looking for. I'll try it out soon. As mentioned, this is only for quick debugging. For production code, I do create structs mapping to the JSON object.

Comment: I also created a library doing exactly this: [github.com/icza/dyno](https://github.com/icza/dyno)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [`stretchr/objx`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/objx) that provide a similar approach.

Example use:

```
document, _ := objx.FromJSON(json)
document.Get("path.to.field[0].you.want").Str()
```

However, unless you really don't know at all the structure of your JSON input ahead of time, this isn't the preferred way to go in golang…

Comment: This approach isn't for production use where I do create structs that map to the JSON structure. This is mostly for quick debugging code that I'm probably not going to use again.

Comment: Thanks Elwinar. I'll check this out. This is close as the `Get` function takes a single selector string but would be nice to automate creation of the string from a slice, e.g. `[]interface{}{"data",0,"links","author","linkage","id"}`. Might be worth a pull request.