# How to parse/deserialize dynamic JSON

Tags: json, go

**Scenario:**

Consider the following is the JSON :

```
{
   "Bangalore_City": "35_Temperature",
   "NewYork_City": "31_Temperature",
   "Copenhagen_City": "29_Temperature"
}
```

If you notice, the data is structured in such a way that there is no hard-coded keys mentioning `City`/`Temperature` its basically just values.

**Issue:** I am not able to parse any JSON which is dynamic.

**Question:** Could anyone have found solution for this kind of JSON parsing? I tried [go-simplejson](https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson), [gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) & default [`encoding/json`](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) but no luck.

**Note:** 
The above JSON is just for sample. And there are lot of applications which are using the current API, So I do not want to change how the data is structured. I mean I can't change to something as follows:

```
[{
   "City_Name":"Bangalore",
   "Temperature": "35"
},...]
```

Then I can define `struct`

```
type TempData struct {
  City_Name string
  Temperature  string
}
```

Comment: Read this http://talks.golang.org/2015/json.slide#1

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can unmarshal into a `map[string]string` for example:

```
m := map[string]string{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(m)
```

Output (wrapped):

```
map[Bangalore_City:35_Temperature NewYork_City:31_Temperature
    Copenhagen_City:29_Temperature]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TTm4vJxaNS).

This way no matter what the keys or values are, you will have all pairs in a `map` which you can print or loop over.

Also note that although your example contained only `string` values, but if the value type is varying (e.g. `string`, numbers etc.), you may use `interface{}` for the value type, in which case your map would be of type `map[string]interface{}`.

Also note that I created a library to easily work with such dynamic objects which may be a great help in these cases: [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://github.com/icza/dyno).

Comment: Note that this only works if you are sure that your json doesn't contain any non-string values. Otherwise you have to use `map[string]interface{}{}`

Comment: This also assumes the struct is only one level deep.. for instance this code won't work with literals and deeper json on the first level.

Comment: @f0ster Yes, which was the asker's case. For arbitrary depth, see this question: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an)

Comment: What will be the scenario when we will have nested json , say temperature also holds other key-values.

Comment: @TinkalGogoi Then unmarshal into a value of type `map[string]interface{}`, or `interface{}`. Also see the linked question+answer above your comment.

Answer (score 10):

Standard `encoding/json` is good for the majority of use cases, but it may be quite slow comparing to alternative solutions. If you need performance, try using [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson). It parses arbitrary JSONs without the need for creating structs or maps matching the JSON schema.

See the example code below. It iterates over all the `(key, value)` pairs of the JSON object:

```
var p fastjson.Parser
v, err := p.Parse(input)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Visit all the items in the top object
v.GetObject().Visit(func(k []byte, v *fastjson.Value) {
    fmt.Printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", k, v)

    // for nested objects call Visit again
    if string(k) == "nested" {
        v.GetObject().Visit(func(k []byte, v *fastjson.Value) {
            fmt.Printf("nested key=%s, value=%s\n", k, v)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: You should mention that you are the author of the library you link to (fastjson)

Comment: It's a common practice to note that you are the author of a library, package etc, when you happen to mention that library, package etc. And it's classy. I do not believe it's a requirement.

Comment: Its good practice to list that you are the author, since you might be biased towards something you, yourself wrote.

Comment: The fact this has a downvote presumably for not saying he wrote `fastjson` is silly. We're all biased toward our own answers on SO. He just happened to have expressed his answer in the form of a very popular library a long time ago... And we have a voting system to de-risk his bias. Saying you wrote a *non-commercial* library is a nice practice, but ridiculous to warrant a downvote. (Assuming that was the reason.)

Comment: can we detect the type of the value in above example ?

Answer (score 6):

Just to add a general answer to how any valid JSON can be parsed; `var m interface{}` works for all types. That includes map (which OP asked for) arrays, strings, numbers and nested structures.

```
var m interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(m)
```

Comment: I have seen this in majority of places, but is it a good practice to use empty interface and is there any other alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using gabs package https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs

"Gabs is a small utility for dealing with dynamic or unknown JSON structures in Go"

Comment: Gabs is awesome