# How do I make use of an arbitrary JSON object in golang?

Tags: json, go

I have an API that receives JSON objects of arbitrary structure.

What's the best way of making use of this data in golang?

Comment: Some related / useful questions for processing arbitrary JSON: [1. How to parse/deserlize a dynamic JSON in go lang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserlize-a-dynamic-json-in-go-lang); [2. Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an)

Comment: Could you post a representative sample? e.g. with a specific view to how the incoming JSON is typed, and and what you'd want to do with it?