# JSON to Go Structure

Tags: javascript, json, go

I have a JSON like

```
{
    "company_id": "Sahil",
    "company_name": "Sahil",
    "ats_operators": ["123"],
    "ids": [
        {
            "duns_id": "1234"
        }
        ],
        "company_symbol": "1234"
}
```

I wanted to convert the above JSON into the Go Structure.

I have one way to do it like:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    CompanyID    string   `json:"company_id"`
    CompanyName  string   `json:"company_name"`
    AtsOperators []string `json:"ats_operators"`
    Ids          []struct {
        DubnsID string `json:"dubns_id"`
    } `json:"ids"`
    CompanySymbol string `json:"company_symbol"`
}
```

But i wanted to use the Go-Map instead of Nested structure.

I tried to use the below code but it is unable to parse the above JSON.

```
type Test struct {
    CompanyID     string              `json:"company_id"`
    CompanyName   string              `json:"company_name"`
    CompanySymbol string              `json:"company_symbol"`
    IDs           map[string][]string `json:"ids"`
    AtsOperators  []string            `json:"ats_operators"`
}
```

Please help and let me know what is the wrong with the above Go structure?

Comment: possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserlize-a-dynamic-json-in-golang

Comment: the `ids` in json is an array of json objects, so can't decode it by map

Comment: it means i need to use structure only?

Comment: @Sahil use struct is the most simple way, otherwise, you can try to achieve `json.Unmarshaler` interface.   https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler

Comment: A list of objects is representable by a slice of maps, not a map of slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use a struct like this:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    CompanyID     string                   `json:"company_id"`
    CompanyName   string                   `json:"company_name"`
    AtsOperators  []string                 `json:"ats_operators"`
    Ids           []map[string]interface{} `json:"ids"`
    CompanySymbol string                   `json:"company_symbol"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this and try. If you are fetching the data from mongodb then keep bson:"" part else just json tags is ok.

```
type DubnsID struct {
  DubnsId string `bson:"dubns_id" json:"dubns_id"`
}

type AutoGenerated struct {
 CompanyID     string    `bson:"company_id" json:"company_id"`
 CompanyName   string    `bson:"company_name" json:"company_name"`
 AtsOperators  []string  `bson:"ats_operators" json:"ats_operators"`
 Ids           map[string][]DubnsID `bson:"ids" json:"ids"`
 CompanySymbol string    `bson:"company_symbol" json:"company_symbol"`
}
```

Comment: I don't wanted to use the structure. You posted the same thing by just extracting the structure from main structure.

Comment: yeah i understood the question in wrong way. I have updated the struct, now try this it will work .You just can't use map[string][]string because your data object is array of object.Either use map[string][]DubnsID or map[string][]interface.