# Create a struct dynamically

Tags: go

I would like to communicate in json with an application using its API.

This application have a struct containing this field:

```golang
CustomFields interface{} `json:"custom_fields,omitempty"`
```

When calling the API this part could be like:

```
"custom_fields": {
  "Field1": "Value1",
  "Field2": "Value2"
}
```

The name of the field for custom fields are not fixed. They could be setup in the application. So I cannot just create a struct. I need to build dynamically the struct inside my code. Is-it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's even possible exactly as you wrote it. Did you actually try it? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: That doesn't create a struct, it creates a map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29347092/13860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building JSON, you can use any struct you have for that `interface{}` variables:

```
data.CustomFields=myStructVar
```

Above, the `myStructVar` is any struct that can be marshaled to JSON.

If you do not have a struct for the custom fields, you can use a `map[string]interface{}`:

```
data.CustomFields=map[string]interface{}{"field1":"value1",
"field2":"value2"}
```

When you're unmarshaling JSON input, the `interface{}` custom fields will be unmarshaled as a `map[string]interface{}` if it is a JSON object, `[]interface{}` if it is a JSON array, or as one of the primitive values (string,float64,bool).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an empty interface for the custom fields, use a `map[string]interface{}`.

```
type Payload struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 int `json:"field2"`
    CustomFields map[string]interface `json:"customFields,omitempty`
}
```

[Full working example](https://play.golang.com/p/YwhBVcHHpWs)

Comment: The application is not written by me: https://github.com/netbox-community/go-netbox/blob/6634a33611e62d201b6890a041f2419015a6c6fa/netbox/models/writable_tenant.go#L42.

Answer (score 0):

I did this piece of code ...
It seems to not work properly, what I did wrong ?

```golang
tenantCustomFields := d.Get("custom_field").(*schema.Set).List()               

  cf := make(map[string]interface{})                                             
  for _, customFieldRaw := range tenantCustomFields {                            
    customField := customFieldRaw.(map[string]interface{})                         
    customFieldName := customField["name"].(string)                                
    customFieldType := customField["type"].(string)                                
    customFieldValue := customField["value"].(string)                              

    if customFieldType == "string" {                                               
      cf[customFieldName] = customFieldValue                                         
    } else if customFieldType == "integer" {                                       
      cfIntValue, err := strconv.ParseInt(customFieldValue, 10, 64)                  
      if err == nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                     
      }                                                                              
      cf[customFieldName] = cfIntValue                                               
    } else if customFieldType == "boolean" {                                       
      cfBoolValue, err := strconv.ParseBool(customFieldValue)                        
      if err == nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                     
      }                                                                              
      cf[customFieldName] = cfBoolValue                                              
    }                                                                              
  }
```

Comment: OK. I found the issue, it's not err == nil but err != nil ... gotcha