# What Go tag should be used while defining struct of a JSON data if "field/key" for some values is varying or not known?

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

While trying to parse a time-series data I found a key field in the JSON data is the timestamp(obviously in string format). But creating a struct for the same beforehand is not possible as I cannot know the timestamp string anyway.

This is how the JSON looks like:

```
"Time Series (5min)": {
        "2020-01-17 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "167.2000",
            "2. high": "167.3400",
            "3. low": "167.0100",
            "4. close": "167.0500",
            "5. volume": "1646699"
        },
        "2020-01-17 15:55:00": {
            "1. open": "166.9000",
            "2. high": "167.1600",
            "3. low": "166.8500",
            "4. close": "167.1500",
            "5. volume": "622999"
        },
        "2020-01-17 15:50:00": {
            "1. open": "166.7241",
            "2. high": "166.9200",
            "3. low": "166.7200",
            "4. close": "166.8999",
            "5. volume": "271723"
        }
    }
```

The struct for the some may look like :

```
type TIMESTAMP struct {
    Open   string `json:"1. open"`
    High   string `json:"2. high"`
    Low    string `json:"3. low"`
    Close  string `json:"4. close"`
    Volumn string `json:"5. volumn"`
}

type TIMESERIES struct {
    TimeStamp TIMESTAMP `json:""`  //DON'T KNOW HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS
}
```

How to handle such a situation? Is there any Go struct tag for the same?

Comment: If the key is unknown, random, dynamic or what have you *always* use a map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse/deserialize dynamic JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserialize-dynamic-json/29347148#29347148).

Answer (score 6):

Keys like `2020-01-17 16:00:00` seems to by dynamically generated and are not fixed, so you can use `map` for arbitary keys like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type TIMESTAMP struct {
    Open   string `json:"1. open"`
    High   string `json:"2. high"`
    Low    string `json:"3. low"`
    Close  string `json:"4. close"`
    Volumn string `json:"5. volumn"`
}


type TIMESERIES map[string]map[string]TIMESTAMP

func main() {
    test := []byte(`{
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2020-01-17 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "167.2000",
            "2. high": "167.3400",
            "3. low": "167.0100",
            "4. close": "167.0500",
            "5. volume": "1646699"
        },
        "2020-01-17 15:55:00": {
            "1. open": "166.9000",
            "2. high": "167.1600",
            "3. low": "166.8500",
            "4. close": "167.1500",
            "5. volume": "622999"
        },
        "2020-01-17 15:50:00": {
            "1. open": "166.7241",
            "2. high": "166.9200",
            "3. low": "166.7200",
            "4. close": "166.8999",
            "5. volume": "271723"
         }
       }
    }`)
    var response TIMESERIES
    if err := json.Unmarshal(test, &response); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", response)
}
```