# call json keys undeclared in golang

Tags: json, go

lets say i have my structure :

```
type LstBQ4422400 struct {
    Sku               string  `json:"sku"`
    Image             string  `json:"image"`
    Nom               string  `json:"Nom"`
    Prix              float64 `json:"prix"`
    Num00195866137462 string  `json:"00195866137462"`
    Num00195866137479 string  `json:"00195866137479"`
    Num00195866137486 string  `json:"00195866137486"`
    Num00195866137493 string  `json:"00195866137493"`
    Num00195866137509 string  `json:"00195866137509"`
    Num00195866137516 string  `json:"00195866137516"`
    Num00195866137523 string  `json:"00195866137523"`
    Num00195866137530 string  `json:"00195866137530"`
    Num00195866137547 string  `json:"00195866137547"`
    Num00195866137554 string  `json:"00195866137554"`
    Num00195866137561 string  `json:"00195866137561"`
    Num00195866137578 string  `json:"00195866137578"`
    Num00195866137585 string  `json:"00195866137585"`
    Num00195866137592 string  `json:"00195866137592"`
    Num00195866137608 string  `json:"00195866137608"`
    Num00195866137615 string  `json:"00195866137615"`
    Num00195866137622 string  `json:"00195866137622"`
    Num00195866137639 string  `json:"00195866137639"`
    Num00195866137646 string  `json:"00195866137646"`
    Num00195866137653 string  `json:"00195866137653"`
    Num00195866137660 string  `json:"00195866137660"`
    Num00195866137677 string  `json:"00195866137677"`
    Num00195866137684 string  `json:"00195866137684"`
}
```

then my code :

```
data := `{"sku": "BQ4422-400", "image": "https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/d099eea8-f876-477a-8333-a84e9acd8584/chaussure-air-jordan-1-high-85.png", "Nom": "Chaussure Air Jordan 1 High '85", "prix": 189.99, "00195866137462": "35.5", "00195866137479": "36", "00195866137486": "36.5", "00195866137493": "37.5", "00195866137509": "38", "00195866137516": "38.5", "00195866137523": "39", "00195866137530": "40", "00195866137547": "40.5", "00195866137554": "41", "00195866137561": "42", "00195866137578": "42.5", "00195866137585": "43", "00195866137592": "44", "00195866137608": "44.5", "00195866137615": "45", "00195866137622": "45.5", "00195866137639": "46", "00195866137646": "47", "00195866137653": "47.5", "00195866137660": "48.5", "00195866137677": "49.5", "00195866137684": "50.5"}`
    var shoe LstBQ4422400   
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &shoe)
```

the problem is i want to call a key this way : shoe.aStringIGotusingAList ,aStringIGotusingAList refers to a number like 00195866137684, so i get 50.5.
it doesnt let me put another thing than the key declared

Comment: Use a map, you can index a map with "dynamic" string value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserialize-dynamic-json/29347148#29347148

Answer (score 1):

The names of the members of the struct (the structs "fields") can be anything you want as long as you specify the "json" name using the struct tag. So using your example you could write the struct this way...

```golang
type LstBQ4422400 struct {
    Sku                   string  `json:"sku"`
    Image                 string  `json:"image"`
    Nom                   string  `json:"Nom"`
    Prix                  float64 `json:"prix"`
    ...
    AStringIGotusingAList string  `json:"00195866137684"`
}
```

You will need to capitalize the fields you want to use with the [stdlib json package](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) because it only works with exported members (capitalized).

You can see a complete example here: https://go.dev/play/p/4XsKcdEz6R9

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer,  i meant i wanted to use the string as a dynamic key directly whch can change. Like in python : dict[AStringIGotusingAList], other comment suggest to use maps  will look into that

Comment: In that case, yeah you can use a map, but you will have to use the keys as they appear in the JSON: `aMap["00195866137684"]`