# Golang parse complex json

Tags: json, parsing, go, nested

I am new to golang and json and currently struggle to parse the json out from a system.

I've read a couple of blog posts on dynamic json in go and also tried the tools like [json2GoStructs](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)
Parsing my json file with this tools just gave me a huge structs which I found a bit messy. Also I had no idea how to get the info im interested in.

So, here are my **problems**:

1. How do I get to the info I am interested in?
2. What is the best approach to parse complex json?

I am only **interested** into the following 3 json fields:

```
Name
Guid
Task -> Property -> Name: Error
```

I'm thankful for every tip, code snippet or explanation!

**This is what I got so far (mostly from a tutorial):**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func readFile(filePath string) []byte {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    checkErr(err)
    return data
}

func main() {
    path := "/Users/andi/Documents/tmp/wfsJob.json"
    data := readFile(path)

    var f interface{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &f)
    checkErr(err)

    m := f.(map[string]interface{})

    for k, v := range m {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case int:
            fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example code is a reasonable start read arbitrary json. What exactly is the question with what you've got?

Comment: You can cut down on the mess from  json2GoStructs by deleting all fields you are not interested in.  The resulting struct definition should be less than 10 lines.

Comment: See example how to deal with this in this answer: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28878037/1705598)

Comment: Hi, I want to end up with a struct like this:

type apiResp struct {
 Name string
 Guid string
 ErrMsg string
}

But I have no idea how to get the value from this json field:

Task -> Property -> Name: Error

Comment: You could try https://github.com/nytlabs/gojsonexplode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can offer you [this easy way](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) to using JSON in Golang. With this tool you don't need to parse the whole json file, and you can use it without struct.

Answer (score 3):

[Gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) is a great solution for fetching a few fields from JSON string. But it may become slow when many (more than 2) fields must be fetched from distinct parts of the JSON, since it re-parses the JSON on each `Get` call. Additionally, it requires calling [gjson.Valid](https://godoc.org/github.com/tidwall/gjson#Valid) for validating the incoming JSON, since other methods assume the caller provides valid JSON.

There is an alternative package - [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson). Like `gsjon`, it is fast and has nice API. Unlike `gjson` it validates the input JSON and works faster when many unrelated fields must be obtained from the JSON. Here is a sample code for obtaining fields from the original question:

```
var p fastjson.Parser
v, err := p.ParseBytes(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Name: %s", v.GetStringBytes("Name"))
fmt.Printf("Guid: %s", v.GetStringBytes("Guid"))
fmt.Printf("Error: %s", v.GetStringBytes("Task", "Property", "Name"))
```