# Go and JSON: how to dynamically load a field

Tags: json, parsing, go

I know how to play with JSON and interfaces in go without too many problems.

I would like to let users choose a JSON element from a JSON string and to store the element pattern in a string so that I can dynamically load it later.
I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

Of course this is easy if I want the `id` element of my JSON , as `id` is the string I'm going to save.

Now let's say I want tags[1].

You can see this gets harder and harder as the JSON gets more complicated. For example I could want to save a pattern similar to `tags[1].data[0].values.id` and so on...

Basically I need to get a well defined element from my JSON and need to save the pattern to a string.

Does GO have a solution to this kind of problem without me implementing my own string parser?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this answer which provides a getter / setter function to get any element from a JSON: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037)

Comment: Take a look at my library [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://github.com/icza/dyno) which does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that I can think of that have tools to solve problems like this. Here are some examples off the top of my head:

1) `github.com/jmoiron/jsonq`

```
jq := jsonq.NewQuery(yourData)
jq.Int("id")
jq.String("tags", "0")
```

2) `github.com/araddon/gou`:

```
jh := gou.NewJsonHelper(yourData)
jh.Int("id")
jh.Strings("tags[0]")
```

3) `https://github.com/elgs/gojq`

The packages are very similar, but slightly different function structure.