# Is there some lib can facilitate the OPERATIONS of JSON in golang?

Tags: python, json, go

When I write python, I like to do that:

```
d = {"apple": "red", "book":["history", "art", "science"]}
print json.JSONEncoder().encode(d)
```

then I get the JSON string

```
'{"apple":"red","book":["history","art","science"]}'
```

but when I want to do that in Golang, things get more complicated, I have to define the struct first:

```
type Gadget struct {
    Apple string
    Book []string
}
g := Gadget{Apple: "red", Book: []string{"history", "art", "science"}}
bytes, _ := json.Marshal(g)
fmt.Println(string(bytes))
```

Is there some golang lib that can help me manipulate the JSON string like python?
I may have many JSON which have different struct to deal with. To define them all is a fussy work. I don't even think there's a lib cause there is no index operater overloading mechanism in golang.

What do you guys say?

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Question would be off-topic as it asks for off-site resources, but it can be solved using the standard lib, so:</sup>

You don't need a struct, you can just use embedded maps and slices which can model all data structures.

Your example:

```
err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(map[string]interface{}{
    "apple": "red",
    "book": []interface{}{
        "history", "art", "science",
    },
})
fmt.Println(err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W10zDTwUro)):

```
{"apple":"red","book":["history","art","science"]}
<nil>
```

Comment: nice answer, thank you. if I have a json string `{"apple":"red","book":["history","art","science"]}
` and I want to add an item to get `{"apple":"red","book":["history","art","science","philosophy"]}
` what would be the most quick way?

Comment: @刘韦菠 That would be this answer: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it into a byte slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037).