# How can I push value into nested map[string]interface{} slice?

Tags: go

Here is an example: https://play.golang.org/p/aQXJzH6Yjo

```
i := make(map[string]interface{})
i["some"] = []interface{}{
        []interface{}{1, 2, "3--"},
        map[string]interface{}{
                "value": "some",
        },
 }
```

How can I push additonal value into `[]interface{}{1, 2, "3--"}` slice? I basically need to create arbitrary datastructure that will be transformed into json. Looked into https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs , but it doesn't seem to allow create nested arrays

Comment: See related question: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037).

Answer (score 3):

It's a little messy, but you can do it as shown here (I've left out the error handling): https://play.golang.org/p/JgZ4fAgRAz

```
i := make(map[string]interface{})
i["some"] = []interface{}{
    []interface{}{1, 2, "3--"},
    map[string]interface{}{
        "value": "some",
    },
}
fmt.Println(i)
var myval []interface{} = i["some"].([]interface{})
var mylist []interface{} = myval[0].([]interface{})

mylist = append (mylist, "Another value")

// Replace the potentially new slice into element 0
myval[0] = mylist

// No need to write back to the map - the slice is a reference type
fmt.Println(i)
```