# Navigation into a map with a string path variable for golang

Tags: dictionary, go, interface, path, navigation

I would like to directly navigate to a value in a map. Lets be more specific with the following go code example which should give me the value of "Walter" directly: (https://play.golang.org/p/tYJsvp39hn)

```
type Signature struct{
     Name string
     Signed bool
}    

path := "Document.Signatures.1.Name"
map := map[string]interface{}{
    "Document": map[string]interface{}{
        "Signatures": []interface{}{
            Signature{ Name: "Hugo", Signed: false },
            Signature{ Name: "Walter", Signed: false },
        },
        "Otherstuff": "asadwa",
    },
    "AlsoOtherStuff": "adwaw",
}

// map.giveMe(path)
// even better (if possible:) map.change(path,"ToThisNewValue")
```

I have searched for solutions, but I can't find any on the internet. Maybe one of you knows how to do this or knows a library to use for me.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can see an example of getting and setting an element given by a path in this answer: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it into a byte seems more complicated then it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an#28878037) (only difference is that path is given as a string slice there, but the concept is the same).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I have a predefined struct to unmarshal my value into. Is it possible to navigate with the Selectors (for struct types) and Index expressions (for maps and slices) as well even if I want to go into several levels? I hope you understand my question

Comment: You can, but for that you'd need reflection (`reflect` package), and it would only work for exported fields.

Comment: Go is not a dynamically typed language. Get rid of these empty interfaces and design a proper data model and you'll be much better of.

Comment: icza thank you very much you solved my problem unfortunatly I cannot upvote comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a lot of reflect calls will be needed if there is no predefined struct.

That being said, you can do it by iterating through the map with type checking on every iteration and handling cases accordingly.

```
// Splitting the path into keys
keys := strings.Split(path, ".")

var value interface{} = map1
for _, key := range keys {
    if value, err = Get(key, value); err != nil {
        break
    }
}
if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("Value:", value)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}


func Get(key string, s interface{}) (v interface{}, err error) {
    var (
        i  int64
        ok bool
    )
    switch s.(type) {
    case map[string]interface{}:
        if v, ok = s.(map[string]interface{})[key]; !ok {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Key not present. [Key:%s]", key)
        }
    case []interface{}:
        if i, err = strconv.ParseInt(key, 10, 64); err == nil {
            array := s.([]interface{})
            if int(i) < len(array) {
                v = array[i]
            } else {
                err = fmt.Errorf("Index out of bounds. [Index:%d] [Array:%v]", i, array)
            }
        }
    case Signature:
        r := reflect.ValueOf(s)
        v = reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(key)
    }
    //fmt.Println("Value:", v, " Key:", key, "Error:", err)
    return v, err
}
```

[Playground code](https://goplay.space/#uRqm6GSEMG)