# Is there any convenient way to get JSON element without type assertion?

Tags: json, dictionary, go, slice

There is some inconvenience while processing JSON response from a web server.

For example, I don't know the data structure (and don't want to model it) of the JSON in advance, and just want to get the value from it!

So, for Python, I can just write

```
value = response["body"][4]["data"]["uid"]  //response is a dictionary
```

But for Golang, I need to do the assertion for every element!

```
value := response["body"].([]interface{})[4].(map[string]interface{})["data"].(map[string]interface{})["uid"]
//response is a map[string]interface{}
```

This is what I write in golang to get the value I need. Do you have any suggestion on it? It there any useful tips for this kind of case?

Comment: If you don't know the model (and for some reason don't want to know?), then no you don't have a choice: you have to reflect over it. However, you're saying this is a json response from a webserver, I'm sure the model is described somewhere.

Comment: If your type assertion works, then you obviously _do_ know the data structure.

Comment: In fact I can model it, but it is a very complex format and it is not a public API which changes a lot. So I monitor the http request/response and write code to automate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you model your JSON object with a struct and you unmarshal into a value of that, then you don't need those ugly indices and type assertions, you can simply refer to struct fields.
Note that you don't have to be afraid of the response being complex, you only need to model the parts you intend to use. E.g. if the response is an object with a hundred fields but you only need 2, then create a struct containing only those 2 fields.

If you don't want to model your JSON object (or can't because it's dynamic), then you may write a general utility function which gets a value based on the *path* (series of map keys and slice indices), which you can see in this answer: [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map[string]interface{}, editing, and marshaling it into a []byte seems more complicated then it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037)

And last you may use 3rd party libs which already contain this helper functionality, such as https://github.com/icza/dyno (disclosure: I'm the author).

Using [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/dyno), it would look like this:

```
value, err := dyno.Get(response, "body", 4, "data", "uid")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per icza you can create struct for JSON object. But in case you are getting JSON structure you don't know from start. Then you can create a dynamic parsing using reflections for interface which will be a recursive function to parse JSON data.

```
func main(){
    var data interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]bytes(file.json), &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var itemData map[string]interface{}
    itemsMap := data.(map[string]interface{})
    jsonParsedObject := interate(itemsMap)  
    log.Println(jsonParsedObject)  
}

func iterate(data interface{}) interface{} {
    if reflect.ValueOf(data).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        d := reflect.ValueOf(data)
        tmpData := make([]interface{}, d.Len())
        returnSlice := make([]interface{}, d.Len())
        for i := 0; i < d.Len(); i++ {
            tmpData[i] = d.Index(i).Interface()
        }
        for i, v := range tmpData {
            returnSlice[i] = iterate(v)
        }
        return returnSlice
    } else if reflect.ValueOf(data).Kind() == reflect.Map {
        d := reflect.ValueOf(data)
        tmpData := make(map[string]interface{})
        for _, k := range d.MapKeys() {
            typeOfValue := reflect.TypeOf(d.MapIndex(k).Interface()).Kind()
            if typeOfValue == reflect.Map || typeOfValue == reflect.Slice {
                tmpData[k.String()] = iterate(d.MapIndex(k).Interface())
            } else {
                tmpData[k.String()] = d.MapIndex(k).Interface()
            }
        }
        return tmpData
    }
    return data
}
```