# How do you read nested Json in Go?

Tags: json, go

I have the following JSON to be decoded, its structure can vary therefore I do not want to use structs:

```
{ "cabinet": "A", "shelve": {"box": "10", "color": "red"} }
```

Following the Golang blog (https://blog.golang.org/json) I have prepared this program to parse it:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    
    respString := `{ "cabinet": "A", "shelve": {"box": "10", "color": "red"} }`
    respBytes := []byte(respString)
    
    var f interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(respBytes, &f)   

    m := f.(map[string]interface{})

    for k, v := range m {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case float64:
            fmt.Println(k, "is float64", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }   
}
```

However, I am wondering how can I access the nested JSON embbedded as value in "shelve".
So far this is the output:

```
cabinet is string A
shelve is of a type I don't know how to handle
```

What shall be done to access inner key/values at shelve? Which strategy is appropriate in Go?

A complete executable code can be found in https://play.golang.org/p/AVMMVQVjY__B

Comment: Pars into a defined struct. Use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ if unsure how to do it and look up any of the literally dozen equivalent questions here.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, the link will be useful in the future. If by parsing into a defined struct you mention the other way that is recommended in the Golang Blog (link included in the question), it can not be used because because as mentioned the JSON structure is not fully defined and can vary. So if I understood the two different ways in which Json can be decoded in Go, maps shall be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shelve` in JSON is an object, so a Go map will be created to model it:

```
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Println(k, "is a map:")
        for k, v := range vv {
            fmt.Println("\t", k, "=", v)
        }
```

With this change output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1yfEUUkU79a)):

```
cabinet is string A
shelve is a map:
     color = red
     box = 10
```

See related question:

[Accessing Nested Map of Type map[string]interface{} in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806951/accessing-nested-map-of-type-mapstringinterface-in-golang/28807170#28807170)

[Is there any convenient way to get JSON element without type assertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377503/is-there-any-convenient-way-to-get-json-element-without-type-assertion/48377560#48377560)

[Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map[string]interface{}, editing, and marshaling it into a []byte seems more complicated then it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037)

Comment: For large and arbitrary json,  I suggest to you to use `json.Decoder` and use `dec.Token()` and I recommend you to write your own map decoder to custom your data.
See that it can be usefull. [link]https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode
[link]https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MapRange.