# Retrieve values from a nested struct

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, range

I am trying to access the values from a nested struct in golang. My final struct is as follows

```
StudentDetails = [{"rollno":3,"name":"John","score":{"sub1":50,"sub2":48,"sub3":45}} , {"rollno":4,"name":"James","score":{"sub1":38,"sub2":35,"sub3":40}}]
```

Iam tring to print the values seperately. For that I tried to add a loop

```
for i, details  := range StudentDetails {

    glog.Info("increment ", i)
    glog.Info("name of student ", details.name)
    glog.Info("mark of sub 1", details.score.sub1)
}
```

But Iam always getting the error

"(type map[string]interface {} has no field or method name""
My structs are as follows

```
type scoreCard struct {
    subject1                int     `json:"id"`
    subject2                int     `json:"id"`
    subject3                int     `json:"id"`

}

type StudDetails    struct {

    roll int
    name string
    score scoreCard
}
```

Comment: Your error indicates you don't actually have structs but maps. For that see [Taking a JSON string, unmarshaling it into a map, editing, and marshaling it into a byte slice seems more complicated then it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037).

Comment: Note that even if you attempted to correctly unmarshal into a struct, or a slice of structs, which you didn't as icza pointed out, it wouldn't really help you because you don't have your fields exported.

Comment: You can use to get `json to go struct` for unmarshaling https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "StudentDetails" variable you created is of type map. i think what you intended to do is this

`var StudentDetails = []StudDetails{ {"roll":3,"name":"John","score":{"subject1":50,"subject2":48,"subject3":45}}, {"roll":4,"name":"James","score":{"subject1":38,"subject2":35,"subject3":40}}, }`

also, there're some inconsistency with your struct field names; the field name used during definition should also be used when creating an instance else you will get an error.

Comment: And any field used in JSON marshaling/unmarshaling must be exported.