# How to get the deepest objects in nested array of objects in Go

Tags: json, go, nested-object

I have a JSON of the following format:

```
[
   {     
      "name": "Tree 1",
      "id": 1,
      "io_id": 12,
      "data": [
         {
            "title": "tree 1 Cond 1",
            "id": 1,
            "childTriggerId": 10,
            "children": [
               {
                  "title": "tree 1 cond 1 Rule 1",
                  "id": 2,
                  "childTriggerId": 11
               }, {
                  "title": "tree 1 cond 2",
                  "id": 2,
                  "childTriggerId": 11,
                  "children": [{
                     "title": "tree 1 cond 2 Rule 2",
                     "id": 2,
                     "childTriggerId": 11
                  }]
               }, {
                  "title": "tree 1 Cond 3",
                  "id": 2,
                  "childTriggerId": 10,
                  "children": [{
                     "title": "tree 1 cond 3 Rule 1",
                     "id": 2,
                     "childTriggerId": 11
                  }]
               }
            ]
         }, {
            "name": "Tree 2",
            "io_id": 14,
            "id": 2,
            "data": [
               {
                  "title": "tree 2 Cond 1",
                  "id": 2,
                  "childTriggerId": 10,
                  "children": [{
                     "title": "tree 2 Rule 1",
                     "id": 2,
                     "childTriggerId": 11
                  }]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to get the deepest objects and pass them to the slice of structs. *By
deepest object I mean the object within "children" key that itself does not
contain "children" key.* Here the objects (or let's say map[string]interface) I
expect to obtain are indicated as "Rule..." in titles.

**Note that it is not certain how nested the objects are.** Passing the data to
the struct is not an issue for me, I can't only figure out the algorithm of
identifying the deepest objects. Here is my main function:

```
type Condition struct {
   ID             int64  `json:"id"`
   Title          string `json:"title"`
   ChildTriggerId int64  `json:"childTriggerId"`
}

type Conditions []Condition

func main() {
   var conditions Conditions
   testJson, err := os.Open("tree-test.json")
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }

   fmt.Println("Successfully opened trees.json")
   defer testJson.Close()
   byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(testJson)
   jsonStruct := []interface{}{}
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &jsonStruct)

   // expect to find deepest objects here
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task without using external packages?
Thank you!

Comment: Model your JSON with structs, unmarshal into that then you can naturally access `children` using selectors. If you don't want to model it, use helpers presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037).

Comment: I've tried to fix your json, please check if is correct.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "deepest objects"? Do you mean specifically in your example that you need the value attached to the "children" key, or do you mean any object as long as its distance from root is the largest?

Comment: @alessiosavi, thanks, but that structure is not really suitable, moreover, that is the structure that I receive from the front-end.

Comment: @EliBendersky, I mean the object attached to the "children" key but which itself does not contain the  "children" key. Thanks for note, I will update the question

Comment: Unfortunately the json data are not correct: Check the json here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: You can certainly do this with the stdlib `encoding/json`. You should just carefully search through your JSON in code. Check out https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/representing-json-structures-in-go/ and https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-json-cookbook/ (See the `findNested` function in this post)