# recursive validation on interface{}

Tags: go

I am trying to validate if particular fields are present in json or not. This json is not fixed . There can be new dynamic fields also I am unable to make use of `struct`. So I have to make use of `interface{}`.

I have to make sure that `serviceName, profileName, name` these fields are always present.

I understand that I can do `type assertion` and loop through it and do type assertion again .
But is there more generic way or a library/package to achieve this?

Once validated the payload, then I have to make a post request to store this data.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := `{
            "id": "123",    
            "customdata": {
                "metadata": [
                    {
                        "device": {
                            "name": "test_name",
                            "description": "test description",
                            "serviceName": "test service",
                            "profileName": "test profile",
                            "additional": {
                                "custom": {
                                    "Address": "modbus-sim",
                                    "Port": "15000",
                                    "UnitID": "0",
                                    "Timeout": "5",
                                    "IdleTimeout": "5"
                                }
                            },
                            "adminState": "test",
                            "operatingState": "UP"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }`
    var p map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    customdata := p["customdata"]
    fmt.Println(customdata)
    metadata := customdata.(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println(metadata["metadata"])
}
```

Here is the [playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/KymRjn1En83)

Comment: You _can_ use structs. Define a struct with the mandatory / required fields, unmarhsal, and check if those fields have valid values. You do not have to model the JSON precisely, only what you want to parse from it.

Comment: I understand this but once payload is parsed to a struct, only existing fields will be converted to struct and missing fields will be omitted. So I will not be able to make a use of parsed struct to make a post request to store data unless I parse it again as an interface.

Comment: You can send the raw data after you've validated the struct fragment.

Comment: Correct, this is only for validation. If you want to use the data, you already have your way of handling it, so you must already have modeled some part of it. You may check the required fields there. Are you saying you're completely dealing with your input as a map? Do try to model some part of it, especially if you need validation or you need to refer to some fields.

Comment: You may of course construct a `get()` helper to extract a value by a path, for an example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877512/taking-a-json-string-unmarshaling-it-into-a-mapstringinterface-editing-an/28878037#28878037

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the json parser library.

Example code that used [jsonparser](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser).

```
    jsonparser.ArrayEach(str, func(value []byte, dataType jsonparser.ValueType, offset int, err error) {
        keys := []string{"name", "serviceName", "profileName"}
        for _, k := range keys {
            _, err := jsonparser.GetString(value, "device", k)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(false)
                return
            }
        }
        log.Println(true)
    }, "customdata", "metadata")
```